# default.latex used by pandoc -t beamer

Tags: beamer, pandoc

default.latex and default.beamer are both in the $HOME/.pandoc/templates directory . 
The command `pandoc -t beamer --verbose` shows the default.latex is used instead of the default.beamer.

Could someone explain to me why.

Thanks in advance

pandoc 2.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default.beamer file is probably a left-over from an older pandoc installation.  Pandoc 2.0 and later use a unified template for both, plain LaTeX and Beamer output.  You can get the default template by running `pandoc -D latex`.